# Python Permutation with multiple conditions (permuting 24 items in 4 groups)

Tags: python, conditional-statements, combinations, permutation, product

I have a hard time figuring out how to permute the following dataset ([data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFDJ9.png)):

It contains 24 Items and each item belongs to one of 4 groups with 6 items. The groups are a result of a combination of two conditions which might be irrelevant here. I want to permute the items with respect to their group in a way, that each permutation only has one item out of each group.

The resulting permutations would look like:

1,7,13,19

1,7,13,20

1,7,13,21

...

6,12,18,23

6,12,18,24

etc.

I already tried itertools and I am able to permute the 24 items or the 4 groups but I don't know how to permute the 24 items with respect to their group.

Comment: `from itertools import permutations` and then `permutations(iterable, num_elements)`. See here https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: Hi, I have tried itertools already and I am able to permute the 24 items or the 4 groups but I don't know how to permute the 24 items with respect to their group.

Comment: So you're looking for all permutations that do not have two elements from same group?

Answer (score 1):

instead of premutation try product also from [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
from itertools import product

groups = 4
elems = 24
lst = list(range(1, elems+1))
elems_per_group = elems // groups
groups = [lst[i*elems_per_group:(i+1)*elems_per_group] for i in range(groups)]

for per in product(*groups):
    print(per)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
group_list = [list(range(i, i + 6)) for i in range(1, 25, 6)]

print(group_list)

permutation_list = [
    [a, b, c, d]
    for a in group_list[0]
    for b in group_list[1]
    for c in group_list[2]
    for d in group_list[3]
]

print(*(permutation_list[i] for i in [0, 2, -2, -1]), sep="\n\n")

print("Total number of items =", len(permutation_list))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
[1, 7, 13, 19]

[1, 7, 13, 21]

[6, 12, 18, 23]

[6, 12, 18, 24]
Total number of items = 1296
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

You have not given how you are representing the table. In my example I use integers for items, you can use any other object instead of integers and it will still give you the desired outcome.

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*items))
[(1, 3, 5, 7), (1, 3, 5, 8), (1, 3, 6, 7), (1, 3, 6, 8), (1, 4, 5, 7), (1, 4, 5, 8), (1, 4, 6, 7), (1, 4, 6, 8), (2, 3, 5, 7), (2, 3, 5, 8), (2, 3, 6, 7), (2, 3, 6, 8), (2, 4, 5, 7), (2, 4, 5, 8), (2, 4, 6, 7), (2, 4, 6, 8)]
>>>
>>> items = [[(1,"a"), (2,"b")], [(3,"c"),(4,"d")], [(5,"e"),(6,"f")]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*items))
[((1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (5, 'e')), ((1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (6, 'f')), ((1, 'a'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')), ((1, 'a'), (4, 'd'), (6, 'f')), ((2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (5, 'e')), ((2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (6, 'f')), ((2, 'b'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')), ((2, 'b'), (4, 'd'), (6, 'f'))]
```